# SCCM Update to 1610 or 1702 not possible

Tags: sccm-2012-r2

I am trying to update SCCM from 1606 to 1702. I ran the Pre-Req check manually (no Errors), since it tended to get stuck from in console. 
If I start the update install (or the pre-req check) the update will change state in Administration, but vanishes for the Monitoring node. It stays in "Installing" or "Checking" state.
Hman.log shows "Failed to calculate hash", but I downloaded it several times now and same Error is shown for 1610, if I try to install that, so I guess somewhere there is a problem with the hash calculation process. CMUpdate.log shows no activity. Setup and PreReq logs are empty as well.
Anyone know where else I can look? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it. The Problem was that the EasySetupFolder needed to be a defined share. The folder itself was shared, but there was no \SERVER\EEasySetupFolder  only a \SERVER\SMS_SiteCode\EEasySetupFolder.

Thought I'd share it, perhaps it relevant for others.